# Hibernate callable attribute throwing error in @NamedNativeQuery in Hibernate 3.2.5

Tags: oracle, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

May i know why callable not working in hibernate 3.2.5 inside @NamedNativeQuery and it throws compilation error. Can anyone know why it is throwing error and please let me know which version it will support.
I need to call oracle stored procedure from Hibernate entity class using @NamedNativeQuery . Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented like below and everything works fine.

Student.class

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQueries(
    @NamedNativeQuery(
            name = Student.UPDATE,
            query = "CALL updateStudent(:studentId, :studentName)",
    )
)
public class Student extends ABaseEntity {

public static final String UPDATE = "Student.update";
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

updateStudent procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATESTUDENT 
(
 studentId IN NUMBER 
,    studentName IN VARCHAR2 
) AS 
BEGIN
  Update student set name = studentName where id = studentId;
END UPDATESTUDENT;
```

StudentDao

```
  @Stateless
  public class StudentDao {
  @PersistenceContext(name = "tngo")
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  public void updateStudent(Long id, String name){
    Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(Student.UPDATE);
    query.setParameter("studentId", id);
    query.setParameter("studentName", name);
    query.executeUpdate();
  }
 }
```

I'm using jpa with hibernate provider version 5.1.0.Final. If you want to return result sets from procedure, you can provide resultClass and resultSetMapping in @NamedNativeQuery annotation.

Comment: I think you are using MySQL database but am using oracle and it has Cursor and how to deal with Cursor .Please give example by connecting to oracle db

Comment: Actually, i'm using Oracle database 12c. Can you give me your full code or at least your procedure so i can simulate and reproduce the problem?

Comment: May be you should try to look at [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/2016/03/22/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedures-and-functions-from-hibernate/)